# can i give permission for Account while packaging

Tags: permissions

i have create a package for my app,and i had created permissions for other users for Account to only create,,url generated for package,i installed somewhere,but i had given create permission,from the other user iam not able to create Account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permissions and permission sets are applied by whomever installs your package. Unless it's installed for **all users** and you have a permission set that gets applied to them, then they won't be able to create accounts. Even then, it's possible (somewhat unlikely, but still possible) that some profiles may not have access to the Account object, so they would need that permission to. You'll need to include all the necessary permissions with your package.

Comment: Are we sure here that we can modify access to standard objects like account when installing a package? One would think that SF would not allow this as it directly modifies permissions for objects NOT in the package. I believe if the package has requirements for standard objects it make it a requirement to install the package but does not apply it via a profile. I could be wrong though...

Comment: @Eric One needs to provide the permissions as part of their permission set, not via a profile. Obviously, there are some profiles where the permissions wouldn't be expected to "take" like for a user with a read-only profile. Regardless, I can only see this working via permission sets, not through providing a profile.

Comment: You can use profiles to assign permissions when you are installing a package. I thought that was what the OP was speaking of "You might see other options if the publisher has included settings for custom profiles. You can incorporate the settings of the publisher’s custom profiles into your profiles without affecting your settings. Choose the name of the profile settings in the drop-down list next to the profile that you need to apply them to. The current settings in that profile remain intact."

Comment: Yes, installing a profile is one way of doing it as well. However, it doesn't allow everyone in the org to use the app if you do that unless you're saying that by doing that they can apply the profile's settings to other users which would be the equivalent of applying permission sets to them.

Comment: correct. But if you do include profiles that have full account access and apply it to a user when installing, does it then give that user full account access if they did not have it before installing the package? That was where I was going...